# Check if message has channel mention

Tags: discord.js

I don't know what method to use to check if the message contains a mention to a channel; if it does, I want to continue with the execution, if not, return an error message.

```
if (message.mentions.channels == true) {
    console.log('Yeah, you used a channel mention');
} else {
    console.log('Hey boy, you have to use a channel mention');
}
```

Can someone clear my doubt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Collection.first()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collection?scrollTo=first) to see if the collection has at least 1 element (that means that the message has at least 1 channel mention).
It should look like this:

```
if (message.mentions.channels.first()) console.log("You used a channel mention.");
else console.log("You didn't.");
```